# Задача на Python - ООП

Tags: python, ооп, классы

**Задача: написать решение используя ООП в Python.**
Дано - атрибуты и методы присутствующие в классе:
Класс "Задвижка". Атрибуты: состояние (OPEN или CLOSE), время открытия-закрытия. Методы: Открыть, Закрыть, в обоих случаях выводится предупреждение об операции и производится пауза, соответствующая времени операции и выводится новое состояние задвижки. Если задвижка уже находится в заданном состоянии выводится сообщение об ошибке.
**Мое решение**:

```
import time as tm
class Gate():
def __init__(self,st,to,tc):
        self.st = st
        self.to = to
        self.tc = tc

def open(self):
    print ("Warning")
    tm.sleep(to)
    if open == st:
        print("State Error")
    else:
        print("Gate Open")
def close(self,):
    print("Warning")
    tm.sleep(tc)
    if close == st:
        print("State Error")
    else:
        print("Gate Close")
Gate(open,3,4)
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас в каждом методе переменные взяты из воздуха (self нет, и другие, типа open или close). open - это ключевое слово, лучше не использовать в качестве имен своих объектов. Состояние задвижки вы нигде не изменяете.

```
import time as tm

class Gate:
    def __init__(self, st, to, tc):
        self.st = st
        self.to = to
        self.tc = tc

    def open(self):
        if 'open' == self.st:
            print("Уже открыта")
        else:
            print("Warning")
            tm.sleep(self.to)
            print("Gate Open")
            self.st = 'open'

    def close(self):
        if 'close' == self.st:
            print("Уже закрыта")
        else:
            print("Warning")
            tm.sleep(self.tc)
            print("Gate Close")
            self.st = 'close'

g = Gate('open', 1, 2)
g.close()
```